# Objective-C Language Syntax - "Type Checking" Constant Strings

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Cocoa and CocoaTouch use string constants frequently, and I'm wondering if there is syntax that enforces (encourages?) a specific set of strings as a method's argument.

For example, `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`'s method `-addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:` takes one of four possible strings for the first argument.

These strings are declared in `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.h` as

```
COREDATA_EXTERN NSString * const NSSQLiteStoreType NS_AVAILABLE(10_4, 3_0);
COREDATA_EXTERN NSString * const NSXMLStoreType NS_AVAILABLE(10_4, NA);
COREDATA_EXTERN NSString * const NSBinaryStoreType NS_AVAILABLE(10_4, 3_0);
COREDATA_EXTERN NSString * const NSInMemoryStoreType NS_AVAILABLE(10_4, 3_0);
```

(FWIW, the `COREDATA_EXTERN` macro expands to `extern` plus some goodies for other platforms)

Beyond (parameter)asserting within the method, is there a way to make sure that Xcode / clang / LLVM encourages only these four values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short and long answer: No. The method accepts a pointer, so you can basically throw anything in there, and if the pointer is of the right type (id or NSString in this case), Clang will happily allow it. If you have own code where you want to tell the user that the method will only accept certain values, make that clear in the documentation and throw an descriptive exception.

Comment: Darn, that's a bummer. I've written code that mapped a new "modern" enum to a static array of strings which gave Xcode completion help, but it provided little payoff in the long run (still need to assert a specific range is passed in). Thanks!